# Print definition of a function in Forth

Tags: forth, gforth

When a word is already defined in Forth, is there a way to print its definition?

I've heard that many of Forth's built-in functions such as `emit`, `drop`, etc. are defined in terms of the language itself, and I'd like to be able to look at their definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually use

```
see emit
```

Which in Gforth gives you something like:

```
: (emit)
  outfile-id emit-file drop ;
latestxt
Defer emit
IS emit
 ok
```